# ORDER BY dynamic SQL statement through PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I have a PHP script, that receives values from an HTML form and combines SQL statement.

I have columns named `col1, col2, ... ,col5`

**Statement**

```
... ORDER BY x, y, z, i, j;
```

is working like this: if checkbox for `col1` is `checked` then `x = col1` and for the rest it's the same. What doesn't work, is when I don't check some boxes - for example I only want to ORDER BY col1 and col4, so I check them both, and the statement produces

```
ORDERY BY col1, y, z, col4, j
```

but I also have checking whether a checkbox for `col1` is `empty`, and if it is, it's changing the value of `x` to **and here I'm stating I've tried putting in** `1=1, NULL, col1` whenever any checkbox is not checked ( and for the rest it's the same `y,z,i,j`).

So what I need is some clever way to make the statement work the way it's supposed to be.

When I changed all values of `x, ..., j` whenever a box was empty to `1=1` the statement worked for only **1** box checked, but when I checked 2 - it didn't order by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just leave a column out entirely if the corresponding check box is not checked?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$ordercolumns = array();
if (isset($_POST['col1'])) {
   $ordercolumns[] = 'x';
}
...
if (isset($_POST['col5')) {
   $ordercolumns[] = 'j';
}
if (sizeof($ordercolumns) > 0) {
   $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . implode(',', $ordercolumns);
}
```